# refactoring Java to get string length

Tags: java, string, int, refactoring

I am starting out with Java and trying to find a neat way of refactoring the below code so that I can set the `firstName` variable as a string and in the same line get and set the `firstNameLength` string length as an integer.

```
String firstName = "Boris";
int firstNameLength = firstName.length();
```

I have been trying variations of the below code but to no avail!

```
int newAge = String firstName = "Boris".length();
```

Comment: Are you sure setting them both in the same line would be an improvement?

Comment: I'm not. I just thought it would be more elegant.
If it makes the code smell, then I won't do it.
Just after some advice on it.
Currently just experimenting with Java, trying to determine the art of teh possible

Comment: In most cases, advice is subjective. What I see as harder to read (1 line) might be more elegant to others.

Comment: I agree. But from a stand point of 'what is possible', I'd like to know what can be done too. All advice/criticism accepted

Comment: Code will not even compile, because `"Boris".length()` returns `int` which you are trying to set to `String` and then `String` to an `int`.

Comment: Yeah I also tried `int newAge = int firstName = "Boris".length();`. But still nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare 2 new variables, but assignment of `firstName` is possible.

```
String firstName;
int newAge = (firstName = "Boris").length();
```

(You could put both in the same line).

I doubt however, that anyone would consider this more readable than

```
String firstName = "Boris";
int newAge = firstName.length();
```

and there are no other benefits.

Comment: I agree. Much better to just use the second example you gave.
Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can **delcare two variables of different type in one statement.**

So you're stuck with 2 statements anyway. So you could put it in one line like this:

```
String name; int length = (name= "Boris").length();
```

But really, what's the point?

I guess if you want to make your code more streamlined, you should think about **why** you need an extra variable holding the length in the first place - as *this can always be computed* later. So you keep *redundant* information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually another solution would be to use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#length-java.lang.CharSequence-) in the following way:

```
int length = StringUtils.length("Boris");
```

But this comes with the Apache Common package.